# date.format is not working

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

I am trying to use the date.format and getting an error that format is not a recognized method. I tried to use thesame in new solution, and I'm getting a correct result. Any idea why .format method is not working? These both are in Javascript.

Comment: how should anyone help you if all we know is: one time it works, the other time not. Post some code relevant to your problem.

Comment: Without looking at your code, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Personally, I have no idea why `.format` method **is** working. JavaScript object `Date` does not have such method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about `Date` type...

It is clear why `format` method is not working - because there is no such method on [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

It is less clear why/when it would work - most likely you are using some script library that modifies `Date` object to have `format` method.

But if you are talking about some other type - `format` function may be present (or added) to any object and it is not possible to suggest anything without code...

I.e. custom object with `format` function:

```
var date = { format:function() {alert("Hi");}};
date.format();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here is the code that is working as expected. <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function show() {
               var date = new Date();
            if (date == null)
                date = '';                        
            var formattedDate = date.format(Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);            
            alert(formattedDate)
        }
    </script>

Comment: @Scuttle - please edit your question and post properly formatted code there.